# uniqueness validation on different scope conditions

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

```
class Game

  field :name, type: String
  field :region, type: String
  field :county, type: String
  field :state, type: String
  field :sport, type: String

  # if sport equals football
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: [:region, :state]}

 # if sport equals baseball
   validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: {scope: [:county, :state]}
```

How can we achieve uniqueness of name specific to a sport but with scope of region&state or county&state?

Comment: I didnt understand why this is downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using a condition:

```
validates :name, presence: true
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: [:region, :state] },
                 if: Proc.new { |g| g.sport == 'football' }
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: [:county, :state] },
                 if: Proc.new { |g| g.sport == 'baseball' }
```

See the [Rails Guides: Conditional Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#using-a-symbol-with-if-and-unless)

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce uniqueness in MongoDB with a compound unique index like so :

```
db.collection.createIndex( { a: 1, b: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

[The MongoDB Doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#unique-compound-index)